# Is there such a thing as an associative queue?

Tags: clojure

I want a clojure data structure that:

- pops from the front
- pushes to the rear
- lets me assoc indices with values (i.e. `(assoc q 0 1)` would set the value of the front to 1)

Is there something like that in Clojure (unfortunately PersistentQueue doesn't fulfill Nr.3), or should I built it on top of vector?

Comment: You could also implement an actual Queue object in Clojure, and then it'd work with other things in Java (and maybe some Clojure land) that expects a queue.

Comment: If you're always adding to one end and taking off the other, then you could keep it in a map indexed by a number. Then you could simply track the number assigned to the head and the tail and remap them when you go to update a value with assoc.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a data structure in standard Clojure that will meet these requirements efficiently.

There was some talk on the Clojure-Dev mailing list about using RRB trees for vectors, which would be a great data structure for this:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/clojure-dev/xnbtzTVEK9A

Not sure how far that has developed - but if you are interested in this kind of data structure then it is definitely worth taking a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not require persistency of the data structure,
you could use `java.util.LinkedList` in your Clojure programs.

Example:

```
;;; Creation
user> (import 'java.util.LinkedList)
java.util.LinkedList
user> (def linked-list (LinkedList. [:a :b :c :d :e]))
#'user/linked-list

;;; Pop from the front
user> (.pop ^LinkedList linked-list)
:a
user> linked-list
#<LinkedList [:b, :c, :d, :e]>

;;; Push to the rear, but costly
user> (.addLast ^LinkedList linked-list :x)
nil
user> linked-list
#<LinkedList [:b, :c, :d, :e, :x]>

;;; Assoc (cf. (assoc linked-list 0 :y)
user> (.add ^LinkedList linked-list 0 :y)
nil
user> linked-list
#<LinkedList [:y, :b, :c, :d, :x]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [sorted-map](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/sorted-map), but you'd have to implement the index part yourself.

For example, to push a value v, you could assoc it with the key produced by incrementing the last key in the map. To pop, you could dissoc the first key in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a deque like python's [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) except you might prefer the indexed access performance characteristics of the c++ `std::deque<T>` whose documentation is somewhat more obtuse.

Java ships with [java.util.Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) implementations which you could just use, much like @tnoda's suggestion of java.util.LinkedList.

If you were rolling your own, the implementation is pretty straightforward for a non-persistent collection, and seems reasonably intuitive to me at least to implement against the "hashed array trees" underlying clojure's hashmap and vector, or directly against vector  initially if the details annoy you.